# In ARCore application using Unity3d, rotate using swipe is not working?

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, arcore

From the below code the zoom is working with two fingers(pinch to zoom) but my rotation is not working using single swipe.For testing i added a text.The text is getting updated with "One touch move" when I swipe the screen.

Cannot understand the zoom is working but the rotation not working.I have downloaded the latest ARcore SDK.I have used the HelloAR example scene to place the object,where HeartModel is where I instantiate on touch when plane is detected.

```
public class HelloARController : MonoBehaviour
{
    /// <summary>
    /// The first-person camera being used to render the passthrough camera image (i.e. AR
    /// background).
    /// </summary>
    public Camera FirstPersonCamera;

    /// <summary>
    /// A prefab for tracking and visualizing detected planes.
    /// </summary>
    public GameObject DetectedPlanePrefab;

    /// <summary>
    /// A model to place when a raycast from a user touch hits a plane.
    /// </summary>
    public GameObject AndyPlanePrefab;
    public GameObject HeartModel;

    /// <summary>
    /// A model to place when a raycast from a user touch hits a feature point.
    /// </summary>
    public GameObject AndyPointPrefab;

    /// <summary>
    /// The rotation in degrees need to apply to model when the Andy model is placed.
    /// </summary>
    private const float k_ModelRotation = 180.0f;

    /// <summary>
    /// True if the app is in the process of quitting due to an ARCore connection error,
    /// otherwise false.
    /// </summary>
    private bool m_IsQuitting = false;


    public static HelloARController helloinstance;

    public GameObject ExampleControl;

    //To spawn only once
    private bool spawned = false;

    private void Start()
    {
        helloinstance = this;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// The Unity Update() method.
    /// </summary>
    public void Update()
    {
        _UpdateApplicationLifecycle();

        // If the player has not touched the screen, we are done with this update.
        Touch touch;
        if (Input.touchCount < 1 || (touch = Input.GetTouch(0)).phase != TouchPhase.Began)
        {
            return;
        }

        // Should not handle input if the player is pointing on UI.
        if (EventSystem.current.IsPointerOverGameObject(touch.fingerId))
        {
            return;
        }

        // Raycast against the location the player touched to search for planes.
        TrackableHit hit;
        //TrackableHitFlags raycastFilter = TrackableHitFlags.PlaneWithinPolygon |
            //TrackableHitFlags.FeaturePointWithSurfaceNormal;

        TrackableHitFlags raycastFilter = TrackableHitFlags.PlaneWithinInfinity;

        if (Frame.Raycast(touch.position.x, touch.position.y, raycastFilter, out hit) && spawned==false)
        {
            // Use hit pose and camera pose to check if hittest is from the
            // back of the plane, if it is, no need to create the anchor.
            if ((hit.Trackable is DetectedPlane) &&
                Vector3.Dot(FirstPersonCamera.transform.position - hit.Pose.position,
                    hit.Pose.rotation * Vector3.up) < 0)
            {
                Debug.Log("Hit at back of the current DetectedPlane");
            }
            else
            {
                // Choose the Andy model for the Trackable that got hit.
                GameObject prefab;
                if (hit.Trackable is FeaturePoint)
                {
                    //prefab = AndyPointPrefab;
                    prefab = null;
                }
                else
                {
                   // prefab = AndyPlanePrefab;
                    prefab = HeartModel;
                }

                // Instantiate Andy model at the hit pose.
                var andyObject = Instantiate(prefab, hit.Pose.position, hit.Pose.rotation);

                // Compensate for the hitPose rotation facing away from the raycast (i.e.
                // camera).
                //andyObject.transform.Rotate(0, k_ModelRotation, 0, Space.Self);


               // andyObject.transform.Rotate(0, 0, 0, Space.Self);
                // Create an anchor to allow ARCore to track the hitpoint as understanding of
                // the physical world evolves.
                var anchor = hit.Trackable.CreateAnchor(hit.Pose);

                // Make Andy model a child of the anchor.
                andyObject.transform.parent = anchor.transform;
            }

            spawned = true;
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Check and update the application lifecycle.
    /// </summary>
    private void _UpdateApplicationLifecycle()
    {
        // Exit the app when the 'back' button is pressed.
        if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.Escape))
        {
            Application.Quit();
        }

        // Only allow the screen to sleep when not tracking.
        if (Session.Status != SessionStatus.Tracking)
        {
            const int lostTrackingSleepTimeout = 15;
            Screen.sleepTimeout = lostTrackingSleepTimeout;
        }
        else
        {
            Screen.sleepTimeout = SleepTimeout.NeverSleep;
        }

        if (m_IsQuitting)
        {
            return;
        }

        // Quit if ARCore was unable to connect and give Unity some time for the toast to
        // appear.
        if (Session.Status == SessionStatus.ErrorPermissionNotGranted)
        {
            _ShowAndroidToastMessage("Camera permission is needed to run this application.");
            m_IsQuitting = true;
            Invoke("_DoQuit", 0.5f);
        }
        else if (Session.Status.IsError())
        {
            _ShowAndroidToastMessage(
                "ARCore encountered a problem connecting.  Please start the app again.");
            m_IsQuitting = true;
            Invoke("_DoQuit", 0.5f);
        }
    }


}
```

I have added another script for zoom and rotate given below.In the fixed update I use the touch to swipe-one finger rotate on y axis which is not working.But at the same time pinch to zoom is working.**So my doubt is whether the rotation of the model is locked to origin?**Rotate script is given below which is another script(Rotate.cs which I have attached to the prefab)

```
  void FixedUpdate()
 {
      if (Input.touchCount > 0 && isLocked==true)
      {
          var touch = Input.GetTouch(0);

          if ((Input.touchCount > 0  && Input.touchCount < 2 && Input.GetTouch(0).phase == TouchPhase.Moved) && !EventSystem.current.IsPointerOverGameObject(touch.fingerId) )
          {
              // Get movement of the finger since last frame
              Debug.Log("One touch Move");
              Vector2 touchDeltaPosition = Input.GetTouch(0).deltaPosition;
              Messagetxt.text = this.gameObject.name;

             this.transform.Rotate(Vector3.up, -touchDeltaPosition.x * rotspeed * Time.deltaTime, Space.World);
           }

           if (Input.touchCount == 2 &&  !EventSystem.current.IsPointerOverGameObject(touch.fingerId))
           {
               // Store both touches.
               Touch touchZero = Input.GetTouch(0);
               Touch touchOne = Input.GetTouch(1);

               // Find the position in the previous frame of each touch.
               Vector2 touchZeroPrevPos = touchZero.position - touchZero.deltaPosition;
               Vector2 touchOnePrevPos = touchOne.position - touchOne.deltaPosition;

               // Find the magnitude of the vector (the distance) between the touches in each frame.
               float prevTouchDeltaMag = (touchZeroPrevPos - touchOnePrevPos).magnitude;
               float touchDeltaMag = (touchZero.position - touchOne.position).magnitude;

               // Find the difference in the distances between each frame.
               float deltaMagnitudeDiff = prevTouchDeltaMag - touchDeltaMag;

               float scale = deltaMagnitudeDiff * perspectiveZoomSpeed * Time.deltaTime;

               Vector3 tt;
               tt.x = scale;
               tt.y = scale;
               tt.z = scale;
                if (this.transform.localScale.x > 0 && this.transform.localScale.y > 0 && this.transform.localScale.z > 0)
                {
                    this.transform.localScale += new Vector3(-scale, -scale, -scale);
                }

                if (this.transform.localScale.x < 1 && this.transform.localScale.y < 1 && this.transform.localScale.z < 1)
                {
                    this.transform.localScale += new Vector3(scale, scale, scale);
                }

                if (this.transform.localScale.x > 3 && this.transform.localScale.y > 3 && this.transform.localScale.z > 3)
                {
                    this.transform.localScale += new Vector3(scale, scale, scale);
                }
            }
       }
 }


public void Lock_Unlock()
{

    if (!isLocked)
    {
        Lock_Unlock_btn.GetComponent<Image>().sprite = Locksprite;
        isLocked = true;
        //  UnityARHitTestExample.InstanceHitManger.m_HitTransform.GetComponent<UnityARHitTestExample>().enabled = false;
        HelloARController.helloinstance.ExampleControl.GetComponent<HelloARController>().enabled = false;
        hidecanvas.SetActive(false);
    }
    else
    {
        Lock_Unlock_btn.GetComponent<Image>().sprite = Unlocksprite;
        isLocked = false;
        //UnityARHitTestExample.InstanceHitManger.m_HitTransform.GetComponent<UnityARHitTestExample>().enabled = true;
        HelloARController.helloinstance.ExampleControl.GetComponent<HelloARController>().enabled = true;
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you reduce your code examples to the minimum required code necessary to reproduce the issue? E.g. I doubt that I need to know the `_ShowAndroidToastMessage` or `Lock_Unlock` methods in order to solve a problem with a rotation ....

Comment: Are you sure you need to multiply by `Time.deltaTime` for the rotation? And is `rotspeed` set to the correct value and not maybe 0? Maybe your rotation angle is just too small?

Comment: _ShowAndroidToastMessage or Lock_Unlock are given in the abv code...and rotate speed I have increased from 10f to 1000f but no effect....the same code works with IOS application using ARKit...confused..

Comment: @derHugo  if ((Input.touchCount > 0 && Input.touchCount < 2 && Input.GetTouch(0).phase == TouchPhase.Moved) && !EventSystem.current.IsPointerOverGameObject(touch.fingerId))
            {
 
                Debug.Log("One touch Move");
                Vector2 touchDeltaPosition = Input.GetTouch(0).deltaPosition;
               
                andyObject.transform.Rotate(Vector3.up, -touchDeltaPosition.x * 10f * Time.deltaTime, Space.World);
    
            }.......If I use the below script in HelloARController Update the swipe is working. ....
why is it not working in another script?

Comment: I'll try it again ;) Yes, _ShowAndroidToastMessage or Lock_Unlock are given in the abv code ... but they should **not** .. they are irrelevant to the issue/question and only cause your code to be very long and cluttered ... remove everything irrelevant for this specific question from your code examples.